# Can you optimize images from a remote URL in NextJS?

Tags: next.js, contentful

For my recent website, I use Contentful as a CMS and NextJS + React as a frontend framework+library combo. I know that the `Image` component in next also does some really handy optimization, including loading much smaller-sized images depending on the render size.

When it comes to external URL's though, I know that this doesn't work as the API returns the image at whatever size it wants regardless of whatever Next wants. However, the contentful API does have an optional URL param `w` that can be set to the width of the desired image in px. Is there any way to take advantage of this with the Next `Image` component?